# how to fix yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, yarn-berry

When I set up the design system
I did `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` and I got the following error.

> YN0001: Error: Your application tried to access color-convert, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

> Required package: color-convert
> Required by: /Users/parksanghyun/.yarn/berry/cache/ansi-styles-npm-4.3.0-245c7d42c7-8.zip/node_modules/ansi-styles/

So I did `yarn add color-convert` and I tried `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` again, but the same error occurred. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a .pnp.cjs in my home folder. Removed it and re-ran `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`. Every thing worked.

Reference:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/5699#issuecomment-1707713273

> Do you accidentally have a .pnp.cjs file in your home folder?